# Prism and Circular Dependence

Tags: wpf, prism, circular-dependency

I have to prism modules that are both dependent on services the other offers.  Is there a way to present interdependence in a way that is safe?  I've thought about combining them into a single module, but they really don't logically combine.

BTW, I know MEF can do this; I know MEF is awesome!  I love MEF.  I can't switch to that technology because it would require an upgrade in the framework and IDE that I can't afford (time wise) right now.

If you are having the same trouble as me go check out [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/).  Its to late for me; save yourselves!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what to do.  The timeout service is not needed by the presentation service at initialization, so I resolved it inside a lazy property.

```
    public ITimeout Timeout
    {
        get
        {
            if (_timeout == null)
                _timeout = _serviceLocator.GetInstance<ITimeout>();

            return _timeout;
        }
    }
```

As the timeout service is registered at initialization of its module, this property is available when it is needed.  Its not ideal, but it works.  The moral of the story is go with [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com).

*Sigh!*

Comment: seems like if these modules are interdependent they should logically be the same module.

Comment: @Anderson, Module decomposition doesn't always best divide along lines of dependency. Sometimes its necessary to have a one-to-one relationship between two separate entities. They are not interdependent as they are both dependent on services provided by the other not the other itself.  Marrying them would be an act of convenience and practicality, not of logic.  I am an idealist until time constraints require me to be pragmatic.  Thankfully, I have a little leeway and a solution that works in the meantime.

Comment: I haven't run across a case where two modules are dependent that couldn't be factored more appropriately (either by putting the services in question in another module or deciding that they were a basic core function that goes in the shell). What's your scenario?

Comment: @Anderson, Probably the latter.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that the logical solution is that the services which are shared between these two modules get extracted into a third module. Your two current modules can then both safely depend on the shared module, you have no circular dependencies and a nicely separated project structure.

Any reason this can't be done?

Comment: logically these are very atomic modules. That is, they each provide a single service.  I'm very good at decomposition, perhaps too good, maybe I should just combine them, but that is logically ugly.  But I suppose its practical.  One is a timeout service that starts the kiosk application over after a certain amount of idle time, the other is a view switching / navigation service.